# They're neither hugging nor embracing. What are they doing?

Tags: vocabulary

Here's a fairly famous painting by Gerome. It depicts Pygmalion and his creation who hasn't yet fully morphed (she's still part-marble):

[image]

They're neither hugging nor embracing, at least not yet. What are they doing? What's the right word?

Comment: What is your definition of hugging and embracing? They are not close enough?

Comment: @Rathony - Right. I mean, the way I see it, proper hugging would imply that one's being pressed to the other's chest. Chest contact.

Comment: But when you do hugging in "greetings", you don't press your chest so hard for contact.  Isn't it hugging?

Comment: Not hugging but embracing.

Comment: @Rathony - There's still some contact. There's none here.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - The dictionary says this about embracing: to take or clasp in the arms; press to the bosom; hug. They're only half-way to it. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Ricky, I don't think the dictionary says that about  embrac***ing***.  The present participle isn't the infinitive. They are embracing or, if you prefer, they are in the process of embracing.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - They've initiated the embrace, but haven't consummated it yet :) or something. They're midway ... halfway to ... Okay, I could use some sleep. Thank you!

Comment: You can say they are hugging or embracing or both.  The terms are not as rigidly defined as you think.  You can stand beside someone, put your arm around their shoulders, and give them a hug.  And you certainly can "embrace" someone from the back.

Comment: The painting depicts the moment when the sculpture of Galatea was brought to life by the goddess Venus and the first kiss between Pygmalion and Galetea. He is  lovingly embracing her.

Comment: She is literally melting, breathing in his arms.

Comment: Dude, they are doing whatever you want them to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nobody's gone out on a limb with an answer yet, so I'll offer one:
"Hoping beyond hope that his creation would inhale her first breath, Pygmalion grasped Galatea by the waist, preventing her from falling, as the stone that kept her erect melted to ever-so-soft flesh."